# jquery split not working

Tags: jquery, split, undefined

I am trying to split a string values seperated by commas using jquery, but it throws split is not defined error. I am using latest version of jquery. Could you please help me on this.

```
Enter th names seperated by commas
    <input type=text id=thVal >
    <input type=button value='hide entered th related columns' id=btnclick>

$('#btnclick').click(function(){
   var array = $('#thval').val().split(",");    
   $.each(array,function(i){
   alert($(array[i]).val());
   });       
});
```

Comment: `.split` is a [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should correct your jquery first selector.
Correct way of selecting your input box by specifying your id selector. Because selector case sensitive.

```
$('#thVal').val().split(',');
```

Look this fiddly example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7YEsF/1/). Since you passing counter i and array to function each. Which will call for each element. So elements can be reached this keyword.

```
$('#btnclick').click(function(){
   var array = $('#thVal').val().split(",");    
   $.each(array,function(i){
   alert(this);
   });       
});
```

Answer (score 3):

IDs are case sensetive. This means that `$("#thval")` will NOT find an element with `id="thVal"`.

I'd also like to point out that if you are using the "latest version of jQuery", then you can just do this instead:

```
document.getElementById('btnclick').addEventListener("click",function() {
    document.getElementById('thVal').value.split(",").forEach(function(part) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(part);
        alert(elem ? elem.value : "Element "+part+" does not exist");
    });
},false);
```

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) is *always* faster, and in this case I even added in an error check for when an element doesn't exist!

Comment: Never heard of Vanilla JS until now. Seriously, plain JavaScript is of course as fast or faster than any library, but not necessarily the fastest to code or the easiest to maintain. So, I'll stick with jQuery for now.

Comment: Its my bad. I acted like a kid and miss typed the case sensitive issue. But why my array is not alerting correct values?

Comment: Your code is way more complex than it needs to be. try this instead: `$.each(array,function(i, val){alert(val);});`

Comment: @yitwail That alerts the contents of the array, not the value of the elements referred to by the array...

Comment: I know that, but since the original code is `alert($(array[i]).val());` I assumed the value of each element of the array resulting from splitting the string is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @yitwail Judging by the Accepted Answer, I guess you're right. Would've been helpful if OP had given expected input/output, but ***no***...

Comment: Well, if the question is halfway intelligible, I give OP the benefit of the doubt. In any event, OP should read the jQuery doc on `$.each()`, then he probably wouldn't need to ask the question